# How do I create a simulated variable to check whether coefficient size arises from technicality?

Tags: least-squares, experiment-design

I am running a regression of y on four variables, two of which are binary variables and two of which are discrete variables which range from 0 to 10. For context, y was data collected from an experiment, and the values of the four independent variables are provided as information to the participants.

I find that the coefficient of the binary variables are larger than the coefficient for the discrete variables. I am wondering if this is simply due to a technicality or whether I should consider this a finding.

I am considering creating "fake variables" to check whether it is really a technicality. I have tried created a fake variable from the discrete variables by halving the value and then adding noise. I do see an increase in the coefficient but this way of checking seems to be quite arbitrary.

Is there a way to check using simulation whether the coefficients are due to the experiment design? I cannot run this experiment again.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is indeed a technicality: since the range of the discrete variables is 10 times larger than the range of the binary ones (assuming they take values 0 and 1), a ten times smaller coefficient for the discrete variables than the binary ones will exert the same influence on the response. Scaling the discrete variable to instead take values $\{0,0.1,\ldots,0.9,1\}$ will improve the situation, in this sense. I'm not sure how a simulation would improve our understanding of the problem, but maybe I've missed something. (we should note that even under this scaling, making a...

Comment: ... direct size comparison like this is somewhat problematic, because it could be that almost none of your discrete data are bigger than 2, or that they concentrate around 5, or some such, whereas the binary data by def concentrate on the boundaries).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think I need to be more specific. The y I am describing is beliefs. My research question tries to see how far off beliefs are from the true y (probability). I constructed probability using ln(prob/(1-prob)) = XB and I try to recover the B from beliefs to see the difference in coefficients. The coefficients for the binary variable are a lot less far off than the coefficients for the discrete variable (the magnitudes for all coefficients are smaller than the original, but a lot smaller for the discrete vars). The participants are aware of the independent variable values.

Comment: Thanks for those details! But they're not relevant :) here's the problem: for a binary variable on its lowest setting, it's contribution is $0\times\beta_b = 0$, on its highest setting, contribution is $1\times\beta_b=\beta_b$, so the difference between the two is $\beta_b-0=\beta_b$. For a discrete variable on its lowest setting, we have $0\times\beta_d=0$, while on its highest setting, we have $10\times\beta_d=10\beta_d$, for a difference of $10\beta_d$. So we see that in order to have the same influence, the discrete coefficient can be ten times smaller than the binary one!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's good to hear that it's not relevant.